# junk chars in mapped drive url to access WebDAV store

Tags: linux, windows, webdav

I came across a strange problem. I m using WebDAV to access files over the network and using windows explorer to map a drive to the webDav URL.

In some windows client systems when I try accessing the file store the WebDAV server is receiving junk character with the URL and the search / get fails to produce any output.

Have anyone faced a similar issue and is there any solution for it.

OS : Oracle Enterprise Linux
WebDAV is deployed as a web application on a weblogic 11g server.

Client: windows 7 SP1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a multi locale keyboard issue.

UPDATE:
It is because of a McAfee endpoint encryption on the client machine. Was able to reproduce it after applying the encryption.